# Android App not displaying in Google Play for Specific Device? for "New Motorola Device" with "Latest Android Version"

Tags: android, google-play, motorola

I have a question regarding why an android app may not display in Google Play for one device but at the same moment does for other devices.  I have researched quite a bit by this point and have found that mainly it comes down to two things:

1. Something about the phone does not match a requirement in the manifest (ie minimum OS version, having a camera, having gps support, etc).
2. The search in Google Play just wasn't the right search term (ie mis-typing or mis-spelling the app's name).

Is there any other reason that could cause an android app not to show up in Google Play for one device while at the same time other devices can see it in Google Play?

Any help is appreciated.  Specifically I'm having trouble where a client had a "New Motorola Device" with the "Latest Android Version" that did not see the app in Google Play, while many other android devices saw the app in Google Play.  Unfortunately I cannot get any more specifics (sour relationship) on which specific Motorola Device & specifically which Android OS version number, so this is all I have to go on.

I realize it's a bit vague, but I was still just seeing if I missed anything "obvious."

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: I am getting same issue. If you found solution please share with me.